# Form-fillable PDF AD&D 2nd Edition character sheets

Tags: adnd-2e, character-sheets, tool-recommendation

I am scouring the net for any type of downloadable AD&D 2nd edition sheets that you can edit and print out for easy information tracking.

Answer (score 12):

I've been able to find a couple. I had better luck searching for [`"form fillable" pdf "ad&d 2e"`](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=%22form%20fillable%22%20pdf%20%22ad%26d%202e%22) instead of "modifiable", since that's the term that Adobe and therefore most PDF creators use. Here are a couple good ones:

- A [character sheet based on the TSR original](http://frothingmug.blogspot.ca/p/10th-age-downloads.html) for a an AD&D setting called 10th Age can be used for other AD&D 2e settings. The only thing that makes it specific to the creator's 10th Age setting is the text in the upper right, where the AD&D 2e logo would have been. As a bonus, it looks *uncannily* like the original green-fill character sheets that TSR used to sell.
- A [minimalist style of character sheet](http://search.4shared.com/postDownload/FkruLPja/PC_Sheet_2__fillable_fields_.html) might suit you better. The fonts are clean sans-serif and the lack of extra decoration will be nicer to your printer's ink/toner supply – especially useful if you plan to print a freshly-updated copy before every session.
- For more of a multi-page character record than a simple *sheet*, [Mad Irishman's character sheets](http://www.mad-irishman.net/pub_dnd_2e.html) are highly regarded. They were orphaned for a while, but his site is back up. The form-fillable one is the v4.6 sheet, second link.

As an alternative to a pre-existing one, if you have access to Adoble Acrobat (not just Reader), you can take an existing PDF character sheet (such as [Mad Irishman's other 2e sheets](http://www.mad-irishman.net/pub_dnd_2e.html) that haven't been made form-fillable yet) and run it through the form wizard to make it form-fillable. That's more work, but it means you can use any PDF sheet you can find.

Comment: The Mad Irishman has a form fillable version of his latest AD&D 2E Character Sheet...

Answer (score -3):

I have had Great sucess using Excell.

Set it so you can only see one page worth of print area, Reduce the cells so that you have to merge 2x6 or 3x6 cells just to type (name).

it takes a bit of practice, but lets you add any image, lines, and text to fully flesh out any number of different character sheet options.

this is JUST a print it out to use it character sheet though.